# Live update table with MVC4 and jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an database just for logs of my applications and now I need to build a web application that reads a table in this database and update the a table in the UI, like a realtime thing.

So, there is any jQuery plugin for something like that? Can you help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `jQuery Realtime` or `SignalR`:

jQuery realtime:

https://github.com/leggetter/jquery.realtime

SignalR:

http://signalr.net/

Comment: Thanks! I think SignalR will solve my problem and another one my team is having in another project! :D